# Animation in iOS7 reverses itself automatically?

Tags: ios, core-animation, catransform3d

I am trying to get better with perspective animations in iOS, so I created a test project to help me understand how things work better. I am performing a CATransform3DTranslation on the subview, but it seems to go give me unexpected results(it moves back to it's initial state when the animation is finished). I am attaching a video of what it looks like, as well as the very basic source code.

http://screencast.com/t/A0kDkzOy2x

```
-(void)show
  //add black view
    UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [blackView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [blackView setAlpha:0.8f];

    [self.view addSubview:blackView];

    //apply animation on view
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 0, 10);
    //perspective transform
    transform.m34 = 1.0/-4.0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        blackView.layer.transform = transform;
    }];
```

}

At the end of the animation, the animations done on the z axis seem to back to normal. The translation on the x-axis seems to remain though..Can someone explain to me what's going on? AutoLayout is off btw.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CABasicAnimation`. You should not mix `UIView` and `CALayer` animations. Mixing results in undefined results.

You should perform the animation like so:

```
CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
transformAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:blackView.layer.transform]; //Setting the from value, to value will be the existing transform.
transformAnimation.duration = 1.0;
transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

blackView.layer.transform = transform;

[blackView.layer addAnimation:transformAnimation forKey:@"transform"];
```

Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) for documentation on `CABasicAnimation`.

Comment: This actually doesn't work. The animation still reverses itself when it is done. I have tried setting the repeat count to 0, the autoreverse to NO, but I am still having problem making the animation persist.

Comment: Can you add a demo project so I can look?